# Get EntityCollection from within another entity

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I have an entityA that contains a EntityCollection of entityB.
I updated the metdata for EntityA with the [include] decoration over the line defining the entityB as follows:

```
[Include]
public EntityCollection<daily> daily { get; set; }
```

in my domainservice class I have a function to retrieve entityA as follows:

```
var summary =
(from S in ObjectContext.summery.Include("daily")
                 where S.daily_number == daily_number
                 && S.month_number == month_number
                 && S.period_id == period_id
                 select S).FirstOrDefault();
            return summary;
```

From the Client I always get count Zero of entityB.
What am I missing here !!

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define the association between `summery` and `daily` with the [AssociationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.associationattribute.associationattribute%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

```
[Include]
[Association("SomeUniqueName", "summery_id", "parent_summery_id", IsForeignKey = false)]
public EntityCollection<daily> daily { get; set; }
```

I am making the following assumptions about your classes

```
public class summery
{
...
    public int? summery_id { get; set; }
...
}

public class daily
{
...
    // Foreign key to the parent summery
    public int parent_summery_id { get; set; }
...
}
```

**Edit:**

In response to Waleed's comment, a composite foreign key association could look like

```
[Association("SomeUniqueName",
             "summery_field1, summary_field2, summary_field3",
             "parent_summary_filed1, parent_summary_filed2, parent_summary_filed3",
             IsForeignKey = false)]
```

Comment: Hello Ed, What if the association require more than one key, for example summery_field1, summary_field2, summary_field3 with parent_summary_filed1, parent_summary_filed2,parent_summary_filed3??